# Fade out element on hover and allow user to select text underneath - possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">Big shiny error goes here</div>
```

Using below CSS, this `div` sticks to the top right corner, even if the page is scrolled.

```
#mydiv {
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Is it possible to have `mydiv` fade out to, say, 10% of opacity on hover and allow user to use page elements underneath, such as select text and copy to clipboard? The idea is that `mydiv` should stay visible at all times, but it should NOT block user's actions.

As an added bonus, it would be nice to select `mydiv`'s text, if no elements are found underneath.

**EDIT:** `hover` + `z-index` approach does not seem to work well, [see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fED2A/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can think of is to give the content area a `z-index` of, say, 1. Then, using `:hover`, give the error div a lower `z-index` to position it behind the main area. This will allow mouse events on the main content. You can also adjust opacity to fade it out as needed. I believe that IE will allow you to click/drag/whatever on the element if there's nothing else in front of it, but Chrome and Firefox will consider it hidden by the content area even if there's "nothing" actually there.

Comment: So, as far as selecting `mydiv`'s text, there is no cross-browser solution - did I get you right? Regarding other requirements, should be okay with setting `z-index` and `opacity` on hover?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm gonna try this tomorrow. +1 and accepted for now.

Comment: No, it does not work well, with a very bad blinking as you hover, which causes eye-strain. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fED2A/). Tested under latest Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: Ah, that would be because when the element moves behind the content, it is no longer being hovered over, so it comes back in front. I'm not entirely sure how to fix that, I'm afraid... The only option I can see is to check for `mousemove` events on the main content, and using that to implement your own custom hover.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this workaround? I'm not 100% clear on what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var id = $('#selector')
  id.mouseover(function(){
    id.fadeOut(800,function(){
      id.hide();
    });
  })
  id.mouseout(function(){
    id.fadeIn(800,function(){

    });
  })
});
```

selector should point the division on top